# Deploying Python, takes forever to build wheel for cryptography

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-cryptography

I'm running a Django Python project in Heroku, and to support the Python cryptography package, my dockerfile contains instructions to first install the non-Python dependencies for that package:

```
run apk add openssl-dev cargo
```

And then my build log shows that deployment builds various wheels. The cryptography wheel takes several minutes to build:

```
  Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for cryptography: filename=cryptography-3.4.7-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=534047 sha256=8c3212278fa23bad7ecfbc54d036e8d35ba9308479d87e8ec39697aed26095dc
```

Is there any kind of precompiled wheel or buildpack or similar that I can use to more speed up my deployments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `apk` command it's likely you're running Alpine Linux. Alpine uses `musl` for its `libc` implementation and this has historically prevented the `cryptography` project from uploading binary wheels. However, with the acceptance of PEP 656 (and a lot of follow up work with auditwheel, pypa/manylinux containers, and pypa/warehouse allowing uploads) we can now upload `musllinux` wheels. `cryptography` uploaded a wheel for cryptography 3.4.8 (x86_64 arch) on September 19, 2021.

To get this wheel there are two prerequisites:

1. You need to upgrade to the latest `pip`. No version older than 21.2.4 supports `musllinux` wheels.
2. You need to ensure you're installing cryptography >= 3.4.8. Older versions do not have these wheels.

If you meet those requirements then `pip install cryptography` will no longer require a compiler (rust or gcc/clang) on Alpine.